# Ffmpeg gui tool to apply filters

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editor, editing

Are there any GUI applications (linux or windows) that allow you to apply ffpmeg filters to a video and observe the changes in a preview in real time?

Comment: that program does not allow you to apply filters

Answer (score 2):

FfmpegGUI seems what you want: https://github.com/RomanSichkaruk/FFmpegGUI

Answer (score 1):

The [Avanti](http://www.videohelp.com/software/Avanti) GUI, for Windows, allows you to preview filters. One has to select the *FFmpeg Script Editor* tab and insert `-vfout filtername` under `[USER_VIDEO_OPTIONS]`. Consult the docs for exact syntax. Once entered, click on the 'Preview Filters' button.

Comment: That is extremely outdated piece of software.

Comment: Avanti is abandoned now but since it's a frontend, what does it matter for this Q?